# Drupal modal form save data twice

Tags: webforms

In my Drupal site I am using [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module [Modal forms (with ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module.

When I place file field (to get opportunity attach files) on the form, form save data twice. But when I delete file field, form work perfect, e.g. save data once. Maybe someone has already faced this problem. Any help will appreciate.

**Image-1**

> [image]

**Image-2**

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
In the file

> modal_forms.pages.inc

inside the `function modal_forms_view_webform($js = NULL, $node)` place `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` after `$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('webform_client_form_' . $node->nid, $form_state);`

Then modal form will save data only once.

Comment: I think, you should not change any original code, you should use hooks or other-way to apply this. What if some update of this subjected module release and you will loose your this manual change after update.

Comment: CodeNext can you detailed explain how to do that or maybe give a link to example ? (I don't understand how to create hooks)